# Best way to build a random team generator

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently learning frontend development and in my quest for developing my skills i've challenged myself with building a random team generator.

Bit of back story; Me and some of my friends regularly hold a COD Warzone tournament inside of our group (12 of us) we randomly select players for each team. However, I want to automate this based on KD ratio (kills/death) with the highest KDs being spilt into 1 of 4 teams. Then I plan to have the same work for Mid and Lower KDs. This way all the teams would have an equal proportion of KD ratios.

Now, this feels quite ambitious for someone who is still very new to JS and I know that I need either a nested array or object to house the name/KD data and then build a function to iterate through each array, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

What would be the best way of housing the player data?

A nested array e.g:

```
var team = [ [Name, KD], [Name, KD], [Name, KD], [Name, KD]];
```

or an object?

```
var users = { Name:KD, Name:KD, Name:KD,Name:KD,};
```

And then building a function that will run through each nested array and based on their KD assign them to a random team variable?

Comment: array of arrays (of all the same entrires) makes no sense, the object (the way you posted that) is invalid. Try at least to come up with some closer to the point examples.

Comment: The best way is the way that fits your needs in the rest of your application. Since you've shown us two lines of pseudo code, there's no way of saying which is "better". In any case, questions asking for opinions rather than facts fare poorly on Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], and what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I would store this data in an array of player objects, something like:

```
const players = [
    { name: 'Bob', kd: 4 },
    { name: 'Sam', kd: 8 },
    { name: 'Danny', kd: 2 },
    { name: 'Chris', kd: 3 },
];
```

Then you could sort that array by kd using sort() like this:

```
players.sort((a, b) => b.kb - a.kb);
```

Then you can push the players one at a time into an object of teams in a for loop:

```
const teams = { team0: [], team1: [], team2: [], team3: [] };
for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    teams['team' + (i % 4)].push(players[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial concept is pretty straightforward, "split up the top K/D players amongst the other teams." To do that you could **sort** your players array by K/D, make the top four the team leads, and then add the next top players to the bottom team.

Example:

```
const players = [
  { Name: 'B', KD: 9 },
  { Name: 'H', KD: 3 },
  { Name: 'E', KD: 6 },
  { Name: 'D', KD: 7 },
  { Name: 'A', KD: 10 },
  { Name: 'C', KD: 8 },
  { Name: 'J', KD: 1 },
  { Name: 'F', KD: 5 },
  { Name: 'I', KD: 2 },
  { Name: 'G', KD: 4 },
]
const sorted = players.sort((a, b) => a.KD - b.KD)
const teamA = [sorted.pop()] // #1 player
const teamB = [sorted.pop()] // #2 player
const teamC = [sorted.pop()] // #3 player
const teamD = [sorted.pop()] // #4 player
const pushIfDefined = (arr, val) => val && arr.push(val)

while(sorted.length) {
  pushIfDefined(teamD, sorted.pop())
  pushIfDefined(teamC, sorted.pop())
  pushIfDefined(teamB, sorted.pop())
  pushIfDefined(teamA, sorted.pop())
}
console.log("Team A: ", teamA)
console.log("Team B: ", teamB)
console.log("Team C: ", teamC)
console.log("Team D: ", teamD)
```

Comment: Ah, Orion's concept is exactly the same and he beat me to the punch. The only difference is he went concise while I went verbose.